# Maven-plugin-plugin default-descriptor error message after upgrade to 3.1.1

Tags: java, maven, plugins, dependencies

I am upgrading my system's Maven runtime from 3.0.5 to 3.1.1 and trying to build my project using `mvn clean install` like I normally would. Using the older Maven runtime, the build would always succeed. However, I am now always getting this error message during the build:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project XYZ: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 48188 -> [Help 1]`

I thought that perhaps it was due to my dependencies and plugins being outdated, so I ran `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` to update my pom.xml versions. That still did not fix this issue. Any ideas?

---

#### UPDATE

By popular demand, here is what my pom.xml file looks like. Note that all dependency and plugin versions were updated by `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` except for Sitebricks and qdox, due to breaking changes that I didn't want to integrate into my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-own-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Cool Maven Plugin</name>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
            <id>someID</id>
            <url>http://some.url.com</url>
    </repository>
    </distributionManagement>   
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.sitebricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitebricks</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.qdox</groupId>
            <artifactId>qdox</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: see updates with pom.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic maven plugin project not working, Mojo plugin descriptors not generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999401/basic-maven-plugin-project-not-working-mojo-plugin-descriptors-not-generating)

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading and using below dependency with config resolved my issue:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
               <!-- see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5346 -->
               <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>descriptor</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Link is dead now, see https://web.archive.org/web/20150508182227/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5346 for archive copy

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and tried probably every hint provided in the possible duplicate [Basic maven plugin project not working, Mojo plugin descriptors not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999401/basic-maven-plugin-project-not-working-mojo-plugin-descriptors-not-generating), but nothing worked. Eventually in turned out that an old version `2.6.1` of the library `com.ibm.icu:icu4j` that was used by some other 3rd party module was responsible. I got rid of the `icu4j` dependency entirely and maven-plugin-plugin run with out problems thereafter.

Comment: This worked for me. The link to https://www.smartics.eu/ is dead, though.

Comment: Indeed it's dead so I removed it as it was just an additional reference,