# Maven plugin annotations broken

Tags: maven

I'm trying to write a Maven plugin, following [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html). When I try to build I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:2.9:descriptor
>   (default-descriptor) on project cmake-dependency-plugin: Error
>   extracting plugin descriptor: 'No mojo definitions were found for
>   plugin: com.iar:cmake-dependency-plugin.' -> [Help 1]

Google points me to [this Jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5346), which, if I read it correctly means that annotations do not work in maven unless a rather cumbersome workaround is employed (which, by the way, did not work for me).

What bothers me more is that it seems to be closed due to some form of Jira-bankruptcy executed by the Maven developers where a bunch of Jira issues have been summarily closed. Since this seems like the primary way to write Maven plugins, I would think that this would be pretty important, but I'm obviously missing something.

Am I misinterpreting the issue, or are maven annotations really broken?

EDIT: This seems to refer to [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999401/basic-maven-plugin-project-not-working-mojo-plugin-descriptors-not-generating), but I would be interested to know more details about why such a seemingly central feature can be left broken like this. Aren't Maven annotations used by Maven plugin developers?

Comment: It would really help, if you showed us your `pom.xml` and provided some more details about your version of Maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you are using an old [maven-plugin-plugin version 2.9 from 2011](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven.plugins%7Cmaven-plugin-plugin%7C2.9%7Cmaven-plugin)...I assume you are working with Maven 3.X and so i would recommend to use an up-to-date version like 3.2. and follow the steps described in the JIRA issue.

Furthermore i would recommend to read the documentation about [maven-plugin-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) where clearly stated that starting with version 3.0 you can use annotations.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <goalPrefix>XYZ</goalPrefix>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-descriptor</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>descriptor</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>help-descriptor</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>helpmojo</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I agree with Karl-Heinz. In addition, you could have a look at one of my OSS projects on Github (https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin) where I'm using annotations for my plugin. You need to be using Maven 3.x for the annotations to work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Upgrading to 3.2 worked much better. Not sure why I was running with such an old version.'