# Maven-plugin-plugin:descriptor goal fails when I want add Log4j to dependencies

Tags: java, maven, log4j, maven-plugin

I have a simple Maven plugin in which I want to use library Log4j. But when I call the command `mvn clean install`, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project test-maven-plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cz.test.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- These cause an exception -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I have one class `Main`:

```
package cz.test.maven;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;

@Mojo( name = "sayhi")
public class Main extends AbstractMojo
{
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        getLog().info( "Hello, world!" );
    }
}
```

When I remove Log4j from dependencies, the plugin will build without any problems. The problem is only with Log4j, other libraries (for example Jsoup) are imported properly. How can I fix this issue?

I tried this, but it didn't help me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999647/10431161

Comment: There's a good chance that you have a transitive dependency that is resulting in conflicts. Are you able to find any other versions of log4j in the dependency graph?

Comment: @shinjw Unfortunately, I can't find any version of log4j in the dependency graph.

Comment: A maven plugin api contains already an API for logging just via `getLog().info..` so no need to add log4j in a plugin..

Comment: An other thing: Why are you using such old versions of maven-plugin-annotations?

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I didn't need to import log4j. Thanks for the answers.